# adding date_add but keeping in mide weekends

Tags: mysql, dateadd

i have a mysql query

```
SELECT CONCAT('document',LEFT(cases.id,26)) AS 'id',
cases.date_modified,
cases.date_modified,
'67421f0a-3f44-1093-1ab6-51750b508349' AS 'assigned_user','1','1','0',
'complete documentation in 4 Days' AS 'name',
'Not Started',
cases.date_modified,
DATE_ADD(cases.date_modified,INTERVAL 4 DAY) AS 'due date','Cases',cases.id,
'P1','Complete Operations Documentation' AS 'description'
FROM cases
    INNER JOIN cases_cstm
ON ( cases.id = cases_cstm.id_c)
WHERE cases.`assigned_user_id` = '67421f0a-3f44-1093-1ab6-51750b508349'
AND cases.`status` = 'Start Administration'
AND `cases_cstm`.`file_location` = 'Operations'
 ORDER BY `date_modified` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

but the problem is on tuesday it will come up for saterday and wednesday it will come up for sunday
and thursday or friday the people will have 2 days les to work?

how can i check that if a weekend fals in the due date to add 2 days?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
(case when weekday(cases.date_modified) = 0
      then DATE_ADD(cases.date_modified, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
      else DATE_ADD(cases.date_modified, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
  end) as 'due date'
```

It just tests for the day of the week and then adds the appropriate duration to pass the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DAYOFWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function will return 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, 3 for Tuesday, ... through 7 for Saturday. You can use it in a condition like so:

```
DATE_ADD(cases.date_modified,
  CASE DAYOFWEEK(cases.date_modified)
    WHEN 3 THEN INTERVAL 6 DAY
    WHEN 4 THEN INTERVAL 5 DAY
    ELSE INTERVAL 4 DAY
  END AS 'due date'
```

The example above adds 6 days for a Tuesday (going to the next Monday), 5 days for a Wednesday (going to the next Monday), and 4 for all others. This is different than what you asked for (where Wednesday goes to the next *Tuesday* rather than Monday), but it may be more appropriate. You can tweak as necessary.